# problem with sql query in android application,

Tags: android

I have a database which has a column of dates in milliseconds. I'm trying to perform a query which allows me to retrieve only the dates that are greater than the current system time and in ascending order.

I've tried this query, but it causes my app to force close. I'm not sure whether the problem is the where clause part or the orderby clause part or both.

Here is what I done, your help would be most appreciative.

> long lowestDate = 0;
>
> long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
>
> String CT = Long.toString(currentTime);
>
> String[]c = {CT};
>
> mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
>
> String[] dates = {KEY_DT};
>
> Cursor getDate = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, dates, dates + "> ?", c, null, null, dates + "ASC");
>
> getDate.moveToFirst();
>
> ```
>   while(getDate.isAfterLast() == false)
>     {
>         lowestDate = getDate.getLong(0);
>         getDate.moveToNext();
>     }
> ```

Comment: If you really want help accept some answers on previous questions please

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`

selection argument description:

> A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

You should correct that. I think that's an issue, because you are calling `toString()` method on `dates` variable, which is an `Array`.